# Console size using Linux in C++

Tags: c++, linux

I am trying to create a program like `more` for Linux without some params. The main idea is that I need to output information from a text file with some arguments in command string. So my main argument is `more -d fileName`.

I know that `more` outputs 23 strings with text, and 24th is that user press `space` and get another screen of information, but I need to take account that user can change size of a console window.

I am trying to use library `#include <sys/ioctl.h>`, but it says that I cannot use such library.  What am I doing wrong?

#### My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>

void printRecord(struct winsize w, std::vector<std::string> lines);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    struct winsize w;
    ioctl(STDOUT_FILENO, TIOCGWINSZ, &w);
    std::ifstream readRecord;
    std::string more("more");
    std::vector<std::string> lines;

    std::cout << "argc: " << argc << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "Argument: " << i << " = " << argv[i] << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;

    if (argv[1] == more)
    {
        std::string str;
        //int n = atoi(argv[2]);
        int numberPages=0;
        readRecord.open(argv[2]);

        while (!readRecord.eof())
        {
            getline(readRecord, str);
            numberPages++;
            lines.push_back(str);
        }
        if (0 == numberPages)
        {
            std::cout << "ERROR: The file is empty" << std::endl;
            exit(-1);
        }
        if (w.ws_row > numberPages)
        {
            printRecord(struct winsize w, lines);
        }
        else
        {
            printRecord(struct winsize w, lines);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
void printRecord(struct winsize w,std::vector<std::string> lines)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < w.winsize::ws_row; i++)
    {
        std::cout << lines[i] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

### Errors:

> ```
> Source.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
> Source.cpp:12:11: error: ‘STDOUT_FILENO’ was not declared in this scope
> ioctl(STDOUT_FILENO, TIOCGWINSZ, &w);
> Source.cpp:44:16: error: expected primary-expression before ‘struct’
> printRecord(struct winsize w, lines);
> Source.cpp:48:16: error: expected primary-expression before ‘struct’
> printRecord(struct winsize w, lines);
> ```

Comment: "but it says that I cannot use such library" - who says that? Do you get a compiler error? You also could have a look at how it is done in the sourcecode of the `less` program under linux, which is available [here](http://www.greenwoodsoftware.com/less/).

Comment: @Axel yes , I have a compiler error.  Thanks for alink !

Comment: @NikitaGusev: We're not psychic, you really should include the error.

Comment: @MSalters Sorry, I've edited it

Comment: @NikitaGusev: You may want to read the guidance on asking questions; we really meant the error text - not a picture of text. It _looks_ like you spelled `ioctl` with a number one at the end, but that's the problem with pictures. (Actually, the code shows you did. It's supposed to be a lowercase l)

Comment: that looks like a 1 instead of an l in ioctl.h

Comment: @MSalters yes, it was my mistake , i had to write l instead 1. Now I have get some errors, check this , please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you used

```
#include <sys/ioct1.h>
```

and there's a typo: **1** instead of **l**. Try with:

```
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
```

instead